# Twisted permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

We consider a set $E$ with an involution (having perhaps fixed points).
We denote orbits by $\lbrace x,\overline{x}\rbrace$ (with $\overline{x}=x$ in
the case of a fixed point).

We consider sequences $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in E^n$ of length $n$ with values
in $E$. Given $i$ in $\lbrace 1,\ldots,n-1\rbrace$, we consider the involution
$\sigma_i$ acting on such sequences as follows:
$$\sigma_i(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},a,b,x_{i+2},\ldots,x_n)=
(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},\tau(a,b),x_{i+2},\ldots,x_n)$$
with $\tau(a,b)$ in $E^2$ defined by
$$\tau(a,a)=(a,a),$$
$$\tau(a,\overline{a})=(\overline{a},a),$$
$$\tau(a,b)=(\overline{b},\overline{a}),\qquad\hbox{if }a\not\in\lbrace b,\overline{b}\rbrace.$$

Claim: This defines a representation of $\mathcal S_n$. (The proof is a straightforward check that the defining
relation $\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1=\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$
holds in all possible cases.)

*Does such a ``twisted'' permutation representation occur somewhere naturally?*

**Complements:** The underlying representation and the underlying element of the
Burnside ring are the same as for the obvious permutation representation
(corresponding to the case of $\overline x=x$ for all $x$ in $E$).

This representation has additional sign-twists (or even more generally,
twists by invertible elements in some ring). Again, nothing new happens
with respect to the same twists applied to the case of a trivial involution
on $E$.

Comment: Can't you just "untwist" this by barring each $x_i$ $m_i$ times, where $m_i$ is the number of $j<i$ for which $x_j\not\in\{x_{j+1},\bar x_{j+1}\}$?

Comment: @DaveBenson I think one has to bar $x_i$ $m_i$ times where $m_i$ is the number of $1\leq j<k\leq i$ such that $x_j\not\in\lbrace x_k,\overline{x_k}\rbrace$.